# How to draw boxes around tags with unfilled lines using openCV?

Tags: python, opencv, pdf, nlp, python-tesseract

I'm using pytesseract to extract text from a pdf and check whether certain tags (such as name and signature) appear with unfilled lines near them. I then use openCV to draw boxes around the tag along with the corresponding unfilled line as such:
[image: box drawn around tag with unfilled line]
However, I'm getting an error where a box is being drawn over a tag that does not have a corresponding line and I'm not sure why.
[image: Tag without corresponding line]

This is a sample image of the pdf that I'm testing:
[image: Sample Image]

This is the code that I tried so far.

`  Tags_Dictionary = [
'name',
'signature',
]
import math
import random

tags_lines = []

## looping through all the pdf words that OCR gave

n_boxes = len(data['level'])

for i in range(n_boxes):

```
# looping dictionary: to see if any word in pdf is matching with our dictionary words
  for j in range(len(Tags_Dictionary)):

    if Tags_Dictionary[j] in data['text'][i].lower():
      tag_name = data['text'][i]

      # details of the tag
      (x1, y1, w1, h1) = (data['left'][i], data['top'][i], data['width'][i], data['height'][i]) #tag

      minDistance = math.inf

      # co-ordinates for the new box we will draw
      newX2,newX22, newY2, newY22 = 0, 0, 0, 0

      drawRect = False

      # looping lines: calculating the distance of the dictionary word with each line: and then storing co-ordinates for the new box where the distance is shortest
      for i,line in enumerate(lines):
        for x2,y2,x22,y22 in line:      #line

          distance = math.sqrt( ((x1-x2)**2)+((y1-y2)**2) )

          if(distance < 300 and distance < minDistance):
              drawRect = True

              minDistance = distance
              newX2 = x2
              newY2 = y2

              newX22 = x22
              newY22 = y22

      if(drawRect):
        newImage2 = cv2.rectangle(img, (x1-10, y1-10), (x22, y1+30), (random.randint(50, 255), random.randint(50, 255), random.randint(50, 255)), 2)
        tags_lines.append(([tag_name, x1, y1, w1, h1], [newX2,newY2,newX22,newY22])) # [tag, line]
        cv2.imwrite('result.png', newImage2)`
```

and this is the following output image of the pdf.
[image: output Image]

Comment: Can you post original image?